# What are the equivalent Option's sequence and traverse methods for \/?

Tags: scala, scalaz

on scalaz 7.2.6, this works:

```
// import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

List(1.some, 2.some, 3.some).sequence
res12: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

List(1.some, none, 3.some).sequence
res13: Option[List[Int]] = None

def doubleSmall(x: Int) = if (x < 30) (x * 2).some else none
List(1,2,3).traverse(doubleSmall)
res15: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(2, 4, 6))
```

The following code does not compile. Is there an equivalent of `Option`'s `sequence` and `traverse` methods for `\/`?

```
List(1.right, 2.right, 3.right).sequence
expecting something like: List(1, 2, 3).right

List(1.right, "error2".left, "error3".left).sequence
expecting something like: Seq("error2", "error3").left


val doubleSmall(x: Int) = if (x < 30) (x * 2).right else "error".left
List(1,2,3).traverse(doubleSmall)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `sequenceU` and `traverseU`:

```
scala> List[\/[String, Int]](1.right, 2.right, 3.right).sequenceU
res3: scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = \/-(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> List(1.right, 2.right, 3.right, "a".left).sequenceU
res4: scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = -\/(a)
```

Note that the first example needs a type hint so that it can pick up the proper implicit `Unapply[Applicative, \/[String, Int]]`.

```
scala> List(1,2,3).traverseU(doubleSmall)
res9: scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = \/-(List(2, 4, 6))
```

Comment: in case there is one or more lefts, this takes only the first one. but I'll accept the answer anyway, because of its simplicity. I've posted another more detailed question on how to get a list of lefts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471935/scalaz-disjunction-sequence-returning-a-list-of-lefts