# scalaz, Disjunction.sequence returning a list of lefts

Tags: scala, scalaz

In scalaz 7.2.6, I want to implement `sequence` on `Disjunction`, such that if there is one or more lefts, it returns a list of those, instead of taking only the first one (as in `Disjunction.sequenceU`):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

List(1.right, 2.right, 3.right).sequence
res1: \/-(List(1, 2, 3))

List(1.right, "error2".left, "error3".left).sequence
res2: -\/(List(error2, error3))
```

I've implemented it as follows and it works, but it looks ugly. Is there a `getRight` method (such as in scala `Either` class, `Right[String, Int](3).right.get)`? And how to improve this code?

```
implicit class RichSequence[L, R](val l: List[\/[L, R]]) {
  def getLeft(v: \/[L, R]):L = v match { case -\/(x) => x }
  def getRight(v: \/[L, R]):R = v match { case \/-(x) => x }

  def sequence: \/[List[L], List[R]] =
    if (l.forall(_.isRight)) {
      l.map(e => getRight(e)).right
    } else {
      l.filter(_.isLeft).map(e => getLeft(e)).left
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around I've implemented a recursive function for that, but the best option would be to use `separate`:

```
implicit class RichSequence[L, R](val l: List[\/[L, R]]) {
  def sequence: \/[List[L], List[R]] = {
    def seqLoop(left: List[L], right: List[R], list: List[\/[L, R]]): \/[List[L], List[R]] =
      list match {
        case (h :: t) =>
          h match {
            case -\/(e) => seqLoop(left :+ e, right, t)
            case \/-(s) => seqLoop(left, right :+ s, t)
          }
        case Nil =>
          if(left.isEmpty) \/-(right)
          else -\/(left)
    }
    seqLoop(List(), List(), l)
  }


  def sequenceSeparate: \/[List[L], List[R]] = {
    val (left, right) = l.separate[\/[L, R], L, R]
    if(left.isEmpty) \/-(right)
    else -\/(left)
  }
}
```

The first one just collects results and at the end decide what to do with those, the second its basically the same with the exception that the recursive function is much simpler, I didn't think about performance here, I've used `:+`, if you care use prepend or some other collection.

You may also want to take a look at `Validation` and `ValidationNEL` which unlike `Disjunction` accumulate failures.

Comment: ValidationNel was the answer I was looking for, thanks!